# Should ClassLoader be thread-safe?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm writing my custom classloader, and am wondering if I should make it thread-safe?
As you can easily see, not all native Java classloaders are thread-safe, only sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader does (and yet, I've checked OpenJDK sources, and in OpenJDK it is not).

Is there a reason java classloaders are not synchronized?
Should custom classloaders be thread-safe?

Comment: Tell which classloader is NOT threadsafe (and yes a ClassLoader must be threadsafe)

Comment: Use of synchronized does not make something thread safe by itself. Given how many different JVMs load classes with the same classloader from multiple threads, I would say it definitely is well demonstrated to be threadsafe. How the threadsafety is accomplished may not be in the way you expect, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassLoader.loadClass()` is synchronized.

Typically a custom classloader won't override this method, but it might override `findClass()`.  Since `findClass()` is called by `loadClass` and is therefore called from a synchronized critical section, it doesn't itself need to be synchronized.

Comment: in fact to implement a WebApp classloader, loadClass must be overriden. The truly sync method is: `private synchronized Class loadClassInternal(String name)` which was (is?) the major gripe for years: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4670071

Comment: Since I'm calling findCalss->loadClass chain directly, I assume, it must be synchronized on the same object as loadClassInternal. I'm yet to find out what specifics are behind loadClassInternal calls

Comment: Sorry, just rechecked, findClass *IS* synchronized, so as long as I'm overriding findClass only, there is no confusion. Thanks!