# Bill Pugh's method of implementing Singleton resulting in "Out-of-order Write"?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, singleton

I went through Bill Pugh's method of implementing Singleton design pattern in Java.

I have a concern regarding it. Correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Please consider the below Bill Pugh's code:

```
public class Singleton {
        // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
        private Singleton() { }
 
        /**
        * SingletonHolder is loaded on the first execution of Singleton.getInstance()
        * or the first access to SingletonHolder.INSTANCE, not before.
        */
        private static class SingletonHolder {
                public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();    // Line 10
        }
 
        public static Singleton getInstance() {
                return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;    // Line 14
        }
}
```

Consider "Thread-1" has called "return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;" on Line-14 for the first time. Now the Singleton class will be instantiated on Line-10.

Before this instantiation is complete, let us say that "Thread-1" is preempted by an another thread- "Thread-2". When "Thread-2" calls "return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;" on Line-14,

Will it return partially constructed Object?

If it returns a partially constructed object, this situation will be an "Out-of-Order Write". Please let me know if I am correct on the above case and share your thoughts.
Also please let me know if this situation can be overcome by any other means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will it return partially constructed Object?

### The answer is *NO*.

```
return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
```

When the first thread will call this line, `SingletonHolder` class will be loaded by the ClassLoader. Now the [classloading is thread-safe process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252071/should-classloader-be-thread-safe), the static variables in the class `SingletonHolder` are then initialized in a thread-safe manner. So the reference of the completely created `Singleton` will be assigned to `INSTANCE` and only then the control will return to the caller thread. Until then all other threads will wait for the classloading process to complete. And thus incomplete created object will not be returned.

Comment: +1 for questioning something you read on a blog. It is a good practice to question everything. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

One way of Implementing Singleton. Instance will be created when loading the class

```
public class Singleton {
            private Singleton() { }
            public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();         
            public static Singleton getInstance() {
                    return INSTANCE;    
            }
    }
```